# Strange behavior spotted c++ sdl2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Using sdl2 I managed to construct "soon-to-be-spaghetti" classes for a game. However when it came to using a function of a class I stumble upon this weirdness.

```cpp
class Player{
    public:
        Player();
        const SDL_Rect *getPositionPtr() const { return &position; }
        const SDL_Rect * getClip(){ return &clip; }
        void eventHandle(SDL_Event & e);
        void move();

    private:
        SDL_Rect position;
        SDL_Rect clip;


        float velocity;
        bool leftkeydown;
        bool rightkeydown;
};

Player::Player(){
    position = {100, 300, 64, 64};
    clip = {0, 0, 64, 64};

    velocity = 0.3;
    leftkeydown = false;
    rightkeydown = false;
}

void Player::eventHandle(SDL_Event & e){
    if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.repeat == 0 ){
        switch( e.key.keysym.sym ){
            case SDLK_a:
                leftkeydown = true;
                break;

            case SDLK_d:
                rightkeydown = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    else if( e.type == SDL_KEYUP && e.key.repeat == 0 ){
        //Adjust the velocity
        switch( e.key.keysym.sym ){
            case SDLK_a:
                leftkeydown = false;
                break;

            case SDLK_d:
                rightkeydown = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Player::move(){
    if(leftkeydown) position.x -= velocity;
    if(rightkeydown) position.x += velocity; // <----- problem here
}
```

leftkeydown seems to work as expected but rightkeydown doesn't do anything to the position.x variable.

Any ideas why it is not incrementing?

Comment: How did you test this? Did you ensure that *at most* one of `leftkeydown` and `rightkeydown` is true at any given point?

Comment: Your velocity is 0.3, and `position` is `SDL_Rect`, which consists of four integers. `100 - 0.3` is 99, but `100 + 0.3` is still 100.

Answer (score 0):

as **[@keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744720/keltar)** commended it happens because at ***int + (float < 0)*** the int stays the same because it converts the result (100.3) from **float** to **int** (100) (thats because one of the values is int) so the position x will stay the same unless you make the velocity int or bigger than 0.